# how to adjust horizontal line

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make an mobile application but the design a page with a line after each segment but right now it is not coming on the place as the above one ( see the code ) can someone help me with the same .

code:

HTML :

```
<div class="main_paragraph">
    <p><b><h3>Mode of notification</h3></p></b><p id="p1">Select mode of     notification</p>
</div>

<div>
    <div id="row11"><img id="msg" src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/60/256/basic-message-icon.png" alt="message_icon"><p id="p2"> 
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Email </p></div>
        <div id="row12"><div id="p3"><select name="flip-3" id="flip-3" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
            </select><div></div><br>

  <div class="h_line"></div>       
              <div id="row21"><img id="img2" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/epic-outlines/30/message-512.png" alt="message_icon"><p id="p2"> 
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp SMS</p></div>
        <div id="row22"><div id="p3"><select name="flip-3" id="flip-3" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
            </select><div></div><br>

            </div>


            <div class="main_paragraph1">
    <p><b><h3>Display Preferences</h3></p></b><p id="p11">Select the default landing page</p>
</div>
<div class="h_line_big"></div>
<div id="sub">
    <div id="row31"><img id="msg1" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unicons-vector-icons-pack/32/large-thumbnails-512.png" alt="message_icon"><p id="p12"> 
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Analytics</p></div>
        <div id="row32"><div id="p34"><div></div><br>

  <div class="h_line"></div>       
              <div id="row41"><img id="img3" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/24/circle_backup_time_history_recent_time-machine_-128.png" alt="message_icon"><p id="p21"> 
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Timeline</p></div>
        <div id="row42"><div id="px"><img id="dot" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/objects/512/Dot-128.png" alt="dot"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_paragraph {
    margin-left:5%;

}

#p1 {
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
}
#msg
{   padding-top:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:10%;
     float:left;

}
#p2
{   text-shadow: none;
    display-block:inline;

}
#row11
{float:left;  
  margin-top:25px;
  width:70%;
  height:100px;

}

#row12
{   float:right; 
    display-block:inline;

    height:100px;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#p3
{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.h_line 
{   width:100%;
    height:1px; 
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;   
    background:black;
}
#row21
{    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px;
    left:0;
    display-block:inline;
    width:70%;

}
#row22
{    float:left;
    display-block:inline;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#img2

{   padding-top:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:10%;
     float:left;
}

.h_line_big
{
    width:100%;
    height:7px; 
    background: #CCCCCC;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;   

}
.main_paragraph1 {
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:5%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;

}

#p11 {
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
}
#msg1
{   padding-top:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:10%;
     float:left;

}
#p12
{   text-shadow: none;
    display-block:inline;

}
#row31
{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px;
    left:0;
    display-block:inline;
    width:70%;

}

#row32
{   float:left; 
    display-block:inline;

    height:100px;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:25px;
}
#p34
{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.h_line 
{   width:100%;
    height:1px; 
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;   
    background:black;
}
#row41
{    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px;
    left:0;
    display-block:inline;
    width:100%;

}
#row42
{    float:left;
    display-block:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:25px;

}
#img3
{   padding-top:15px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:10%;
     float:left;
}
#sub {
    margin-top:100px;
}
#dot
{   margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;

    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}

.h_line1
{
    width:100%;
    height:1px; 
    top:52px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;   
    background:black;
}
#px
{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    min-height:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/w3wbksb6/2/

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the issue you are facing. Could you explain it and also described what you are trying to achieve please.

Comment: Explain the errors you see in your fiddle, what's wrong with the output?

Comment: I am soo sorry i attached a wrong fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/w3wbksb6/2/

Comment: @paul and  question is now edited.

Comment: Check your HTML, it's full of invalid syntax, especially your closing tags are often mixed up or are missing backslashes.